# Can I simultaneously search for multiple tag types when Screen Scraping with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, linq, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack, linq-to-objects

Although still in a malleable state, this code works:

```
public List<string> GetParagraphsListFromHtml(string sourceHtml)
{
    var pars = new List<string>();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(sourceHtml);

    var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    var document = getHtmlWeb.Load("http://www.montereycountyweekly.com/opinion/letters/article_e333a222-942d-11e3-ba9c-001a4bcf6878.html"); 
    var pTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
    int counter = 1;
    if (pTags != null)
    {
        foreach (var pTag in pTags)
        {
            pars.Add(pTag.InnerText);
            MessageBox.Show(pTag.InnerText);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("done!");
    return pars;
}
```

What I really want, though, is to grab all text elements (in order), not just paragraph tags ("SelectNodes("//p")).

Is it possible to get multiple tag types simultaneously, a la something like (pseudocode):

```
var textTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1", "//h2", "//h3", "//p", );
```

...or a LINQified version, such as:

```
    foreach (var par in doc.DocumentNode
        .DescendantNodes()
        .Single(x => x.Id == "body")
        .DescendantNodes()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "h1" || x.Name == "h2" || x.Name == "h3" || x.Name == "hp" || ))
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work for you:

```
doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.Where(x => (x.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text));
```

This will grab all the text elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, with the example page shown above, the Message Box shows empty strings (nothing) a few times, and that's all.